# Meaning of Summation Symbol in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This might seem basic or too simple to ask, but I cant find it in my university lectures or exercises. Here is the part I dont understand:

Let $(A_i)_{i\in\{1,2,3\}}$ be a family of sets with $A_1= \{4,5,6\},~A_2 = \{a, b, c, d\}$ and $A_3 = \{a, 4, 40\}$

Construct the two Sets:

(i) //This wasnt a problem

(ii) $\sum_{i\in\{1,2,3\}} A_i$

I dont understand the usage of the summation symbol in this context and couldnt find any sources online with a similar task.

I dont think $\{(4, a), (5, b, 4),\ldots\}$ is correct, since its not a cartesian product. I am a beginner, so excuse the simple question :)

Comment: Please use MathJax to format math in questions and not code blocks (see [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help with that).

Comment: This is not standard notation: you need to know how $\sum_{i\in I} A_i$ is defined for sets $A_i$; it could be the case that your course instructor used this notation to mean the usual union, with its standard notation being $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ instead of $\sum_{i\in I}A_i$

Comment: i just found a small note in one of the exercises pointing exactly that out, thank you. Also i will use MathJax the next time for better formating :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the sum notation for sets means that you take disjoint unions. For example $\{a\} \cup \{a\} = \{a\}$ whereas $\{a\} + \{a\} = \{a_1,a_2\}$ (you make two different copies of $a$). Adding sets amounts to taking their union, but while forcing them to be disjoint.

Formally: $\sum_{i \in I} X_i = \{(i,x) \mid i \in I, x \in X_i \}$

Comment: I have never seen sum of sets to mean disjoint union. The standard notation for disjoint union is $\sqcup$ or $\dot\cup$ or $\uplus$

Comment: In my experience $\sum_{i\in I}X_i$ is simply an obsolete notation for $\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$.

Comment: This is one of the notations presented in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union and it is justified by the fact that the cardinality of the sum is the sum of the cardinalities. In my field, people use this a lot, but well, in this case it seems that it was denoting plain union